# Request.Form not populated when using the HTTP PUT method (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-put

I'm attempting to process the body of an HTTP PUT request, but it seems that the MVC engine (or perhaps the ASP.NET stack underpinning it) isn't automatically parsing & populating the request's Form collection with the body data.

This does work as expected when doing a POST.

Note that the request's InputStream property does contain the expected data, and obviously I can build my own key/value collection using that, however I would have expected PUT to work the same way as a POST.

Am I missing something here?

Example action method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Put)]
public ActionResult Purchase(int id, FormCollection data)
{
  // Do stuff with data, except the collection is empty (as is Request.Form)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(VS.90).aspx):

> The Form collection retrieves the
>   values of form elements posted to the
>   HTTP request body, with a form using
>   the POST method.

So instead of using `Request.Form` I would recommend you writing a custom model class that will hold the request data and pass it as action parameter. The default model binder will automatically populate the properties from the key/values passed in the request stream:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Put)]
public ActionResult Purchase(MyCustomModel model)
{
    // Do stuff with the model
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net does not support PUT out of the box for custom requests. If you are using not the built in capabilities to generate the PUT url try adding `X-HTTP-Method-Override` with value of `PUT` in headers, form, or query string.